# NgRx: CustomRouterStateSerializer serialize() called multiple times

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

I have implemented a NgRx Router-Store for my Angular project in the common way (https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/configuration).

My "Problem" is that the serialize-method of my `CustomRouterStateSerializer` seems to be called multiple times, when a routerLink gets triggered by clicking the corresponding html element of a component.

You'll find a minimal example application of the following description on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/rweisse/router-store-test).

---

**My implementation**

This is my `router.reducer.ts` file which contains the RouterStateUrl-Interface and the Serializer-Class:

```js
export interface RouterStateUrl  {
    url: string;
    queryParams: Params;
    params: Params;
    random: number;
}

export class CustomRouterStateSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl > {
    serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl  {
        const { url, root: { queryParams } } = routerState;

        // Random number to be able to match console output to router-state later (with NgRx Store DevTools)
        const random = Math.random();
        console.warn(`CustomRouterStateSerializer called by ${url}, random: ${random}`);

        let state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = routerState.root;
        while(state.firstChild){
            state = state.firstChild;
        }
        const { params } = state;
        return {url, queryParams, params, random };
    }
}
```

This is my `app.module.ts` file:

```js
/*[...]*/
imports: [
    /*[...],*/
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
        metaReducers,
        runtimeChecks: {
            strictStateImmutability: true,
            strictActionImmutability: true
        }
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.development }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
        serializer: CustomRouterStateSerializer,
        navigationActionTiming: NavigationActionTiming.PostActivation,
    }),
]
/*[...]*/
```

---

**Detailed description and output**

Lets say my app currently displays an overview of some projects (url: /projects) and a routerLink gets triggert to switch the component to show an overview of jobs (url: /jobs). The console will print three messages:

- `CustomRouterStateSerializer called by /projects, random: 0.0896547559010431`
- `CustomRouterStateSerializer called by /jobs, random: 0.7662025752972623`
- `CustomRouterStateSerializer called by /jobs, random: 0.07919176016307328`

NgRx Store DevTools are showing several Actions as expected:

`@ngrx/router-store/request`

```
router: {
    state: {
        url: '/projects',
        queryParams: {},
        params: {},
        random: 0.31957045879116797
    },
    navigationId: 2
}
```

`@ngrx/router-store/navigation`

```
router: {
    state: {
        url: '/jobs',
        queryParams: {},
        params: {},
        random: 0.7662025752972623
    },
    navigationId: 3
}
```

`@ngrx/router-store/navigated`

```
router: {
    state: {
      url: '/jobs',
      queryParams: {},
      params: {},
      random: 0.7662025752972623
    },
    navigationId: 3
}
```

As you can see the state of `@ngrx/router-store/navigation` and `@ngrx/router-store/navigated` are identical. Furthermore their random number is identical to the second console output. The random number of `@ngrx/router-store/request` belongs to the state of the old projects-view.

The output of NgRx Store DevTools seem to be as expected. But I don't understand when and what called the serialize method where the other console outputs were triggert. I can not find any random numbers of the first and the third console output in any state. Now I'm asking myself if I have made an error (implementing stuff) or if this is just normal behaviour (but why?). Maybe some of you can tell me.

Comment: I have added a minimal example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/rweisse/router-store-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried out a few things, but in the end it helped to take a look at the source code of `@ngrx/router-store`.
What this module essentially does is to listen to all router events and dispatch actions. The important piece of code is this one: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/router-store/src/router_store_module.ts#L240-L275

> But I don't understand when and what called the serialize method where the other console outputs were triggert.

You can see here that there are three situations where `serialize()` can be called:

- at `NavigationStart` (directly)
- at `NavigationEnd` (through the `dispatchRouterNavigation()` and `dispatchRouterNavigated()` methods)
- at `RoutesRecognized` (through `dispatchRouterNavigated()`)

Each of these events call `serialize()` separately to avoid derived state: The router is the source of the router state and it can change at any given time.
Thus, when the serialized state is needed, it will not be stored somewhere but newly calculated each time instead.
This is why the function is being called multiple times. However, since the serializer function should be pure, this is not a problem at all but rather part of the design.

> I can not find any random numbers of the first and the third console output in any state.

The [reducer](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/router-store/src/reducer.ts#L27) will only put the router state into the store on `navigation`, `cancel` and `error` – but not on `request` and `navigated`.
That means, the only random number you will see in the store is the one originating from the `navigation` action.
All others are just used "on the way".

> Now I'm asking myself if I have made an error (implementing stuff) or if this is just normal behaviour (but why?).

Your implementation looks good and you can be relieved: This is normal and intended behavior!  Just be aware that your serializer function should be pure.

Hope this helps!